# Trying to getAudioInputStream to URL (java.net.MalformedURLException) java

Tags: java

I am trying to getting AudioInputStream from an audio URL. This URL is not a qualified URL because the audio file is inside of my project which I want to load using audio input stream. But I am getting the java.net.MalformedURLException. is there any solution?

**following is my code**

```
   public AudioClipPlayer()
 {  try
  { 
      AudioInputStream audio_inputstream=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream("media/local/ua/on.wav");

  catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
}
```

**following is exception**

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: media/local/ua/on.wav
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put complete url something like

> file:///drive:/.../media/local/ua/on.wav

the local file protocol **file** is missing.

Comment: audio file is in my local directory. so how  can i put host or port

Comment: Ah, ok, how about change to "file:///drive:/.../media/local/ua/on.wav"?